# MVC JQuery Datepicker fails to fire after jquery hides and shows the date field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

In MVC I use an Editor Template in the shared folder for my views to activate the datepicker.
So my Date.cshtml looks like this;

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLongDateString() : string.Empty,
    new { @class = "datefield", type = "date", style = "width:200px;" })
```

And in my view I have;

```
<td class="rightCell">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Assessment.SsipAccreditationDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(
                    model => model.Assessment.SsipAccreditationDate, "*")
</td>
```

This field is defined in the View Model as

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("SSIP Accreditation Date")]
    public DateTime? SsipAccreditationDate { get; set; }
```

And the script that joins it up is this;

```
var initialiseDate = function() {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }).next("button.ui-datepicker-trigger")
            .attr("tabIndex", "-1");
}
```

And the problem is that the datepicker only pops up when there is a date already in there. If the field is null, it does not popup.

In ie developer tools, the markup for the field looks like this;

```
<input name="Assessment.SsipAccreditationDate" class="datefield hasDatepicker" id="Assessment_SsipAccreditationDate" style="width: 200px;" type="date" value="" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field SSIP Accreditation Date must be a date.">
<button tabindex="-1" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" type="button">...</button>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="Assessment.SsipAccreditationDate">*</span>
```

So what is going wrong?

EDIT - a key part of the problem is that in jquery I show and hide the date and that seems to make the difference. On another page I do not have this problem with this date field.

Answer (score 0):

try

if the current value is null the set

```
$("#datefieldid").val('');
```

this will change things , the datapicket doesn't like null i guess

Comment: Hi Emil, I have edited the question as I realise that the key factor in this happening is that in jquery I hide and show the date field and this makes the difference, but I do not know why. When I show the date field I call the initialiseDate function again to ensure the datepicker works, but it does not.